# foreign key simbolo extraño

Tags: pgadmin

Estoy haciendo llaves foráneas y en el índice de la derecha (la parte grafica), el símbolo de la llave foránea siempre ha sido una llave gris.

Pero ahora la ultima llave foránea que hice tiene como simbolo una llave dorada con una "X" roja.

No entiendo que significa esto. He hecho pruebas y se sigue comportando como una llave foránea normal pero me preocupa que pueda generar un problema a futuro

[image: Símbolo llave foránea extraño]

Comment: Probablemente la llave foránea no coincide con la llave primaria de la tabla que quieres empatar. Revisa las relaciones entre llaves de la tabla que quieres relacionar. Puede que sea los tipos de datos, osea, estas tratando relacionar un varchar con un int, o algo parecido. ¿Qué gestor de bd usas? y ¿Cuál motor de base de datos (postgresql, mysql, sqlserver)?

Comment: @fer.trecool pgadmin corresponde a PostgreSQL.

Comment: no había visto el tag de la pregunta, gracias por la aclaración @padaleiana